# how to return all rows from oracle procedure using multiple cursors

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

I have 5 tables, using oracle procedure how to fetch selected columns from these five tables and to return all rows as a simple select query with out joins. i have written this procedure but i am unable to get the desire result.

```
    create or replace
    PROCEDURE NOTIFICATIN_REPORT_TEST(
        para_claim_no IN VARCHAR2,
        O_CRM_ACC_CAL_GARAGE out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_ACC_CAL_GARAGE%type,
    O_CRM_ACC_DAM_COMP out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_ACC_DAM_COMP%type,
    O_CRM_ACC_DATE_TIME out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_ACC_DATE_TIME%type,
    O_CRM_ACC_DESC out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_ACC_DESC%type,
    O_CRM_ACC_FIR out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_ACC_FIR%type,
    O_CRM_ACC_INJ_DET_TPPD out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_ACC_INJ_DET_TPPD%type,
    O_CRM_DRI_LICENSE_NO out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_DRI_LICENSE_NO%type,
    O_CRM_DRI_NAME out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_DRI_NAME%type,
    O_CRM_DRI_RELATION out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_DRI_RELATION%type,
    O_CRM_DRI_VALID_UPTO out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_DRI_VALID_UPTO%type,
    O_CRM_INS_ADDRESS out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_INS_ADDRESS%type,
    O_CRM_INS_CLIENT_ID out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_INS_CLIENT_ID%type,
    O_CRM_INS_CONTACT_NO out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_INS_CONTACT_NO%type,
    O_CRM_INS_MOBILE_NO out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_INS_MOBILE_NO%type,
    O_CRM_INS_NAME out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_INS_NAME%type,
    O_CRM_INS_OFFICE out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_INS_OFFICE%type,
    O_CRM_INS_VEHICLE_NO out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_INS_VEHICLE_NO%type,
    O_CRM_POLICE_STN_NAME out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_POLICE_STN_NAME%type,
    O_CRM_REMARKS out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_REMARKS%type,
    O_CRM_VEH_USED_FOR out CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.CRM_VEH_USED_FOR%type,
    O_ADDRESSLINE1 out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.ADDRESSLINE1%type,
    O_ADDRESSLINE2 out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.ADDRESSLINE2%type,
    O_CITYDISTRICT_NAME out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.CITYDISTRICT_NAME%type,
    O_CONTACTPERSON_NAME out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.CONTACTPERSON_NAME%type,
    O_COUNTRY_NAME out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.COUNTRY_NAME%type,
    O_EMAIL_ID out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.EMAIL_ID%type,
    O_LANDMARK out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.LANDMARK%type,
    O_MOBILE_NUMBER out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.MOBILE_NUMBER%type,
    O_NATUREOFLOSS_DESCRIPTION out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.NATUREOFLOSS_DESCRIPTION%type,
    O_PINCODE out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.PINCODE%type,
    O_POLICY_NUM out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.POLICY_NUM%type,
    O_RELATION_WITH_CUSTOMER out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.RELATION_WITH_CUSTOMER%type,
    O_REPAIRER_NAME out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.REPAIRER_NAME%type,
    O_STATE_NAME out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.STATE_NAME%type,
    O_TEL_NUMBER out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.TEL_NUMBER%type,
    O_VILLAGE_NAME out INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.VILLAGE_NAME%type,
    O_MAKE out INTRFC_MOTOR_RISK_VIEW.MAKE%type,
    O_MODEL out INTRFC_MOTOR_RISK_VIEW.MODEL%type,
    O_AGENT_NAME out INTRFC_POLICY_VIEW.AGENT_NAME%type,
    O_BRANCH_OFFICE_DESC out INTRFC_POLICY_VIEW.BRANCH_OFFICE_DESC%type,
    O_MANUAL_COVERNOTE_NO out INTRFC_POLICY_VIEW.MANUAL_COVERNOTE_NO%type,
    O_RISK_END_DATE out INTRFC_POLICY_VIEW.RISK_END_DATE%type,
    O_RISK_START_DATE out INTRFC_POLICY_VIEW.RISK_START_DATE%type,
    O_CHASIS_NO out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.CHASIS_NO%type,
    O_DATE_OF_NOTIFICATION out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.DATE_OF_NOTIFICATION%type,
    O_ENGINE_NO out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.ENGINE_NO%type,
    O_NOTF_FIR_DATE out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTF_FIR_DATE%type,
    O_NOTIF_ADDRES_POLICE_STATN out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTIF_ADDRES_POLICE_STATN%type,
    O_NOTIF_CP_EMAIL out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTIF_CP_EMAIL%type,
    O_NOTIF_DRIVER_OTHER_INFO out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTIF_DRIVER_OTHER_INFO%type,
    O_NOTIF_LOSS_LOC_TYPE out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTIF_LOSS_LOC_TYPE%type,
    O_NOTIF_OTHER_REMARKS out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTIF_OTHER_REMARKS%type,
    O_NOTIF_PLACE_PARKING out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTIF_PLACE_PARKING%type,
    O_NOTIF_SURVEY_TO_DONE out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTIF_SURVEY_TO_DONE%type,
    O_NOTIF_SVC_PROV_CONTACT_NUM out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTIF_SVC_PROV_CONTACT_NUM%type,
    O_NOTIF_SVC_PROV_INFORMED out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTIF_SVC_PROV_INFORMED%type,
    O_NOTIF_SVC_PROV_NAME out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTIF_SVC_PROV_NAME%type,
    O_NOTIF_TOYOTA_POLICY_NO out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.NOTIF_TOYOTA_POLICY_NO%type,
    O_PRODUCT_CODE out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.PRODUCT_CODE%type,
    O_STATUS out MO_CLAIM_MASTER.STATUS%type


         )
    AS
      reference_num_var VARCHAR2(50);
      claim_no_var      NUMBER;
      crm_sl_no_var     NUMBER;
      CURSOR c1
      IS
        SELECT NV.claim_no,
          NV.reference_num,
          NV.ADDRESSLINE1,
          NV.ADDRESSLINE2,
          NV.CITYDISTRICT_NAME,
          NV.CONTACTPERSON_NAME,
          NV.COUNTRY_NAME,
          NV.EMAIL_ID,
          NV.LANDMARK,
          NV.MOBILE_NUMBER,
          NV.NATUREOFLOSS_DESCRIPTION,
          NV.PINCODE,
          NV.POLICY_NUM,
          NV.RELATION_WITH_CUSTOMER,
          NV.REPAIRER_NAME,
          NV.STATE_NAME,
          NV.TEL_NUMBER,
          NV.VILLAGE_NAME
        INTO claim_no_var,
          reference_num_var,
          O_ADDRESSLINE1,
          O_ADDRESSLINE2,
          O_CITYDISTRICT_NAME,
          O_CONTACTPERSON_NAME,
          O_COUNTRY_NAME,
          O_EMAIL_ID,
          O_LANDMARK,
          O_MOBILE_NUMBER,
          O_NATUREOFLOSS_DESCRIPTION,
          O_PINCODE,
          O_POLICY_NUM,
          O_RELATION_WITH_CUSTOMER,
          O_REPAIRER_NAME,
          O_STATE_NAME,
          O_TEL_NUMBER,
          O_VILLAGE_NAME
        FROM INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW NV
          --WHERE NV.claim_no=para_claim_no;
        WHERE NV.POLICY_NUM=para_claim_no ;
      t1 c1%rowtype;
      CURSOR c2
      IS
        SELECT PV.AGENT_NAME,
          PV.BRANCH_OFFICE_DESC,
          PV.MANUAL_COVERNOTE_NO,
          PV.RISK_END_DATE,
          PV.RISK_START_DATE
          INTO
          O_AGENT_NAME,
    O_BRANCH_OFFICE_DESC,
    O_MANUAL_COVERNOTE_NO,
    O_RISK_END_DATE,
    O_RISK_START_DATE

        FROM INTRFC_POLICY_VIEW PV
        WHERE PV.NUM_REFERENCE_NUMBER=reference_num_var;
      t2 c2%rowtype;
      CURSOR c3
      IS
        SELECT RV.MAKE,
          RV.MODEL
          INTO
          O_MAKE,
    O_MODEL
        FROM INTRFC_MOTOR_RISK_VIEW RV
        WHERE RV.reference_num=reference_num_var;
      t3 c3%rowtype;
      CURSOR c4
      IS
        SELECT CM.notif_crm_sl_no,
          CM.CHASIS_NO,
          CM.DATE_OF_NOTIFICATION,
          CM.ENGINE_NO,
          CM.NOTF_FIR_DATE,
          CM.NOTIF_ADDRES_POLICE_STATN,
          CM.NOTIF_CP_EMAIL,
          CM.NOTIF_DRIVER_OTHER_INFO,
          CM.NOTIF_LOSS_LOC_TYPE,
          CM.NOTIF_OTHER_REMARKS,
          CM.NOTIF_PLACE_PARKING,
          CM.NOTIF_SURVEY_TO_DONE,
          CM.NOTIF_SVC_PROV_CONTACT_NUM,
          CM.NOTIF_SVC_PROV_INFORMED,
          CM.NOTIF_SVC_PROV_NAME,
          CM.NOTIF_TOYOTA_POLICY_NO,
          CM.PRODUCT_CODE,
          CM.STATUS
          INTO
          crm_sl_no_var,
          O_CHASIS_NO,
    O_DATE_OF_NOTIFICATION,
    O_ENGINE_NO,
    O_NOTF_FIR_DATE,
    O_NOTIF_ADDRES_POLICE_STATN,
    O_NOTIF_CP_EMAIL,
    O_NOTIF_DRIVER_OTHER_INFO,
    O_NOTIF_LOSS_LOC_TYPE,
    O_NOTIF_OTHER_REMARKS,
    O_NOTIF_PLACE_PARKING,
    O_NOTIF_SURVEY_TO_DONE,
    O_NOTIF_SVC_PROV_CONTACT_NUM,
    O_NOTIF_SVC_PROV_INFORMED,
    O_NOTIF_SVC_PROV_NAME,
    O_NOTIF_TOYOTA_POLICY_NO,
    O_PRODUCT_CODE,
    O_STATUS


        FROM MO_CLAIM_MASTER CM
        WHERE CM.claim_no = claim_no_var;
      t4 c4%rowtype;
      CURSOR c5
      IS
        SELECT CRM.CRM_ACC_CAL_GARAGE,
          CRM.CRM_ACC_DAM_COMP,
          CRM.CRM_ACC_DATE_TIME,
          CRM.CRM_ACC_DESC,
          CRM.CRM_ACC_FIR,
          CRM.CRM_ACC_INJ_DET_TPPD,
          CRM.CRM_DRI_LICENSE_NO,
          CRM.CRM_DRI_NAME,
          CRM.CRM_DRI_RELATION,
          CRM.CRM_DRI_VALID_UPTO,
          CRM.CRM_INS_ADDRESS,
          CRM.CRM_INS_CLIENT_ID,
          CRM.CRM_INS_CONTACT_NO,
          CRM.CRM_INS_MOBILE_NO,
          CRM.CRM_INS_NAME,
          CRM.CRM_INS_OFFICE,
          CRM.CRM_INS_VEHICLE_NO,
          CRM.CRM_POLICE_STN_NAME,
          CRM.CRM_REMARKS,
          CRM.CRM_VEH_USED_FOR
          INTO
          O_CRM_ACC_CAL_GARAGE,
    O_CRM_ACC_DAM_COMP,
    O_CRM_ACC_DATE_TIME,
    O_CRM_ACC_DESC,
    O_CRM_ACC_FIR,
    O_CRM_ACC_INJ_DET_TPPD,
    O_CRM_DRI_LICENSE_NO,
    O_CRM_DRI_NAME,
    O_CRM_DRI_RELATION,
    O_CRM_DRI_VALID_UPTO,
    O_CRM_INS_ADDRESS,
    O_CRM_INS_CLIENT_ID,
    O_CRM_INS_CONTACT_NO,
    O_CRM_INS_MOBILE_NO,
    O_CRM_INS_NAME,
    O_CRM_INS_OFFICE,
    O_CRM_INS_VEHICLE_NO,
    O_CRM_POLICE_STN_NAME,
    O_CRM_REMARKS,
    O_CRM_VEH_USED_FOR
        FROM CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW CRM
        WHERE crm.crm_slno=crm_sl_no_var;
      t5 c5%rowtype;
    BEGIN
     OPEN c1;
        FETCH c1 INTO t1;
        CLOSE c1;
        reference_num_var := t1.reference_num;
        claim_no_var      := t1.claim_no;
        OPEN c2;
        FETCH c2 INTO t2;
        CLOSE c2;
        OPEN c3;
        FETCH c3 INTO t3;
        CLOSE c3;
        OPEN c4;
        FETCH c4 INTO t4;
        CLOSE c4;
        crm_sl_no_var :=T4.notif_crm_sl_no;
        OPEN c5;
        FETCH c5 INTO t5;
        CLOSE c5;
    END NOTIFICATIN_REPORT_TEST;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom data types and pipelined functions.
You create a type for your "record" template:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE O_MY_OBJECT AS OBJECT (
  MY_DATE                       DATE
, MY_NUMBER                     NUMBER
, MY_VARCHAR                    VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Then you create a type for a table of your record template:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE T_MY_OBJECT AS TABLE OF O_MY_OBJECT;
```

And then create a pipelined function that returns your table object:

```
FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION(V_MY_PARAM IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN  T_MY_OBJECT
  PIPELINED
AS
V_MY_OBJ_VAR O_MY_OBJECT := O_MY_OBJECT(null, null, null);
BEGIN
      SELECT
            SYSDATE
          , 10
          , 'HELLO WORLD! -> ' || V_MY_PARAM
      INTO
          V_MY_OBJ_VAR.MY_DATE
        , V_MY_OBJ_VAR.MY_NUMBER
        , V_MY_OBJ_VAR.MY_VARCHAR
      FROM
          DUAL;

      PIPE ROW(V_MY_OBJ_VAR);

  RETURN;
END MY_FUNCTION;
```

In your case you will pipe a row every time you need it from each of the five cursors' loops.
Once you've created such function you can get records from it with a table query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(MY_FUNCTION('SOME ARGUMENT VALUE, IF NEEDED'));
```

Comment: Hi Andrea thanks you for answer but I am new to the concept of Pipeline Functions. I tried using your sample code. But i failed to achive the result. If you could help me with your code for two tables then i will be able to do the same with my 5 tables.

Comment: First: you have to identify the set of columns (with relative types) you want in your result table (what would you do in a UNION query).
Second: define an object type with that structure and the corresponding table as in my example.
Third: loop in your cursors c1, c2, c3 and so on and put values in the object you created (another time, what you would do in a UNION query). In every loop cycle you will pipe (put it on the result table) the object. Only when you have accomplished with the first task then you can go through my example.

Comment: Hi Andrea thank you i got my output. But still i am not very clear with the third step. how many loops i have to use. Currently i am using only one loop and one cursor. Also want to know how to post my script into this so that you can see my code.

Comment: Don't know ho to paste code in comments, sorry... Anyway, in your code you FETCH every cursor in a table of cursor%recordtype (in your code I see five cursors, not one). Here you should loop for every cursor and pipe every record (of each different type) in your (just one) custom type.